# How to set different color for each active tab in Ionic

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to set color for active tab in Ionic, both for icon and text. The problem is in color: it's different for each tab, i.e. tab1 have color "red" if active, tab2 have color "green", etc.
In CSS I wrote a rule:

```
.tab-button[aria-selected="true"] {
    color: color($colors, title-orders);
    ion-icon {
        background: color($colors, title-orders);
    }
    .tab-button-text {
        color: color($colors, title-orders);
    }
```

There is an `<a>` tag, which have value `[aria-selected="true"]` and 2 children elements: `<ion-icon>` and `<span>`. The `<ion-icon>` tag has specific class icon, for example, custom-decrees, so I can use rule, to change the icon color to color I need. But text is in the `<span>` tag, so I can't change it's color in CSS.
How I can change color of `<ion-icon>` and `<span>` colors, based on condition for ? They are neighbor elements.
As far as I know, there is no CSS-way to do it. Also, because some magic in Ionic, I can't set specific class for tab in HTML - added class doesn't appear where I need - it appears much later.
How to do this in Angular using JavaScript?

UPD: Done with SCSS. Example looks like:

> `ion-icon[ng-reflect-name="custom-orders"] {background: color($colors, title-orders);}
>   ion-icon[ng-reflect-name="custom-orders"] + span {color: color($colors, title-orders);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `>` to select the `ion-icon`  elements that are direct children of an `a` element with the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` to select the `span` elements that come immediately after that `ion-icon`:

```
a > ion-icon + span{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively you can just use `a > span {...}` to select all `span` elements that are direct children of `a` elements if there's nothing more inside them.

As for adding classes to tabs, I started a new "tabs" project with ionic and I can see the html for the tabs section in `src/pages/tabs/tabs.html` where it even has a color selector so I assume you can add particular classes to the tabs there? You can also take a look at `src/theme/variables.css` to see the global theme being used if you need bigger palette changes.

EDIT: finally, you can use [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) in combination with the previous tools to target each different `tab` and change the css of any of its children, for example, as seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbnq7155/12/), where clicking each line will change the `aria-selected` value but each span will get a different colour.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'll try to explain my problem:

Comment: There is a 5 tabs in my app for now, and they are generated like `<a> > <ion-icon> + <span>` each. And the active tab has value `[aria-selected="true"]`, while 4 others tab have `[aria-selected="false"]`. So this is how I can detect active tab. It's not a problem. And here I can change color for active tab. But I can set color for ANY active tab, whatever it be - first or second or last. And I can change color in CSS for active, or use through variable in `variables.scss`. But I can't say "1st active color - red, 2nd - blue, etc".

Comment: And this is what I exactly need - if 1st tab active - it should be light-blue (both icon and text), if 2nd tab active - it should be purple.
Colors taken from pages.
So `<a>` tag could be active or not. It's first moment. Second moment I have to check - what tab is active. Is `<ion-icon>` tag has class `custom-orders` or `custom-decree`. If it has, for example, `custom-orders` - then color need to be set to some value both for `<ion-icon>` and for `<span>`. This is where I stucked for all day.

Comment: How about using [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to set the css for each tab when active, then?

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbnq7155/5/), I'll update the answer if this is what you needed. You can erase the "aria-selected=true" property and see the colouring disappear.

Comment: Dear friend! I tried hard, and finally got the answer.
I used `ion-icon[name] {color}` to set color of icon and `ion-icon[name] + span {color}` to set color of text immediately after icon. So now it works fine! Thank you very much, you saved me!

Comment: Oh, that's a workaround! I'll add what I linked last for completeness then, good luck!